# Angular service containing http get call not working with ng-repeat

Tags: http, angularjs, get

I have an angular controller that calls a service. The service is responsible for returning data from a json file.

controller:

```
function projectController($scope, ajaxServices) {
$scope.projects = ajaxServices.getProjects();
}
```

service:

```
projectManagerApp.factory('ajaxServices', function ($http) {
  return {
    getProjects : function () {
      $http.get('projects.json', { data: {} }).success(function (data) {
      if (window.console && console.log) {
        console.log("objects returned: " + data.length); // shows # of items
      }  
      return data   //nothing ng-repeated, no console errors.
    })
    // Exact same data from json file hard-coded, works fine
    // when not commented out.
    // return [{ "id": 1, "name": "Project 1 }, { "id": 2, "name": "Project 2" }]
    }
   }
});
```

html: `ng-repeat="project in projects"`

In the success function I can see the data returned in the console log but if I try to return the data the ng-repeat ul element on my page is empty. In the same service if I simply return the same data logged to the console hard coded (outside of the success function, of course it works just fine.

How can I return the data into the ng-repeat using my ajax call?

I'm just as new to Plunker as I am Angular but here is my attempt at a Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ALa9q6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` is asynchronous, therefore the call to `getProjects` will return nothing. Using `$q` you can receive an instance to a promise which will receive the data when available.

**Using $q**

Here an example using `$q`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/U72oJblvrVEgYt2mTmU2?p=preview

**Using $resource**

Alternatively, you can use `$resource` especially if your server code is RESTful, which requires adding the following dependency in your scripts:
`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular-resource.js`

This is a 1st review of your code to use `$resource`: http://plnkr.co/edit/tLOAaXZHdGgWOok3Sdc8?p=preview

But you can simplify and shrink it more to this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pKO6k6GxJ1RlO8SNvqUo?p=preview

This is the new `app.js` file:

```
angular.module('app',  ['ngResource'])
  .factory('ProjectsService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('projects.json');
  }])
  .controller('ProjectsController', ['ProjectsService', '$scope', function(ProjectsService, $scope) {
    $scope.projects = ProjectsService.query();
  }]);
```

Find more information about `$resource` here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Many good answers posted to this question but I found "using Q" in your answer was the most useful for my situation. I wrote a asmx web service to return the data EXACTLY as it is in the json file, as a matter of face it writes the string directly to the http response. I don't know if that would be considered "RESTful" server code. regardless. great answer thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $q. Example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldBNCiu8g8T1cezkV5HQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`$http` performs asynchronously and may or may not be finished at any given point in time which is why your return statement dont work.

Use `$q` or simply handle the promise inside the controller:

Service:

```
projectManagerApp.factory('ajaxServices', function ($http) {
    return {
         getProjects : function () {
            return $http.get('projects.json', { data: {} })           
        }
    }       
});
```

Controller:

```
function projectController($scope, ajaxServices) {
    ajaxServices.getProjects().success(function (data) {
        if (window.console && console.log) {
            console.log("objects returned: " + data.length);
        }                          
        $scope.projects = data
    });
}
```

<kbd>**[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BcnFyy5K7vZZCFzNlGgB?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to be loaded before the page
Is loaded you can use 'resolve' property
For the module.
Have a look in the docs for details.