# AngularJS ng-repeat for a service call over http doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a single array item and in this array are complex JSON objects, I need to access the json objects with ng-repeat in angularjs. I have setup a fiddle.

Any solutions is welcome.

I would need to get the following from JSON:

reputation
profile_image
last_edit_date
question_id

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(reputation, link) in items.owner">{{reputation}}: {{link}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-repeat="maybe some other items could be gathered in this div">

    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3ZFb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V3ZFb/3/:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items.items">
        {{item.owner.reputation}}: {{item.owner.link}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need questions_id? Also I can't modify json.

Comment: `{{item.question_id}}`. After my answer, it should be intuitive.

Comment: I am doing this as a Service Implementation and the approach you suggested doesn't work. I cant add $scope to json, it is coming from a source and I dont have control over it.

Comment: apohl's solution did not modify the json, all he did was fill in the ng-repeat html properly. This will work even if you get the json from a service, you just have to assign it to $scope.items within your controller like you did in your fiddle.

Comment: It is still not working, I guess the problem is similar to this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137350/angular-service-containing-http-get-call-not-working-with-ng-repeat
but still not sure how to use a promise in my case..
Any Ideas?