# I am having to marshal $apply to get my ng-repeat to work, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, apply

I have this function that adds data to a $scope object.

```
function newUT(unit, apply) {
    newGuid(function (data) {
        var newTask = {
            id: data,
            TaskName: 'New Task',
            _showdetails: true,
        };
        unit.tasks.push(newTask);
        apply();
    });
}
```

This function is assigned to $scope in the controller by
        $scope.newUT = newUT;

Before I put in the *array* object, the ng-repeat wasn't updating. *newGuid* is a legacy app that is used to get Guids from the server, and put then in the local filestore Guid index table. So I cannot quite eliminate that code.

This code is called by:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="newUT(unit,$apply)">
```

So the issue is that I really don't like passing *$apply*, but if I don't I cannot get the array to update.

1. Is there a better way?
2. I saw [Angular service containing http get call not working with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137350/angular-service-containing-http-get-call-not-working-with-ng-repeat)

   1. But I'm not sure how I would wrap my newGuid call for a *q* call
   2. Since newGuid is a shared server call, I don't know if that is even the right way.

Is there a better way? Is what I am doing acceptable?

Comment: You have a controller that defines function newUT. That controller should get a scope injected into it. That scope can provide the $apply function, so you should not need to pass it into the function.

Comment: `$scope.newUT = newUT;` is in the controller, but `function newUT(unit, apply){...}` is defined outside of the controller.

Comment: Ok, so same applies, make $scope.newUT a wrapper function, not a reference to the original. $scope.newUT = function(unit) { newUT(unit); $scope.$apply(); };

Comment: I had tried to wrap `function newUT(unit, apply){...}` as `function newUT($scope){return function(unit){...}}` but by the time that the returned function got called $scope had shifted to undefined. I also moved the whole code into controller as `$scope.newUT = function(unit){...}`, and as `$scope.newUT = function(unit, $scope){...}` and still no success. I suspect that the asynch of  newGuid is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Ah, not sure how I missed that callback! I would probably use a promise in this case. The newUT function should return a promise, and in your callback to newGuid you would resolve the promise. In your controller you would call the then() function of the promise to assign data and do the $apply.

Comment: You could try wrapping the newGuid function with a service that uses the $timeout service to wrap the callback.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with $scope.$apply around newGuid(). You're just saying go outside the Angular digest loop and do this function so that angular is aware of the function occurring.

Comment: @gonzofish, that is exactly what I am doing. This code works, but it has what I consider having a smell to it. Meaning If I start seeing this from other developers I am highly concerned about the maintainability of the code in the long term. Where as implementing q as *aet* suggests, may be more code, but it may be more maintainable. I will play with both ideas more, and post results in plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) service can help here. If you set up a wrapper service for your newGuid method then you can wrap the callback in a $timeout:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59qdX/1/)

```
app.service('svc', function($timeout){
    this.getGuid = function(cb){
        getGuid(function(value){
            $timeout(function(){
                cb(value);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I will add this to my test cases and see how it works compared to the other suggestions.